# How can I convert date like '/Date(1546120800000+0200)/' returned by WCF rest endpoint to 'DD.MM.YYY HH:mm' format in Angular?

Tags: angular, rest, wcf

I am calling a WCF service using a rest endpoint in an Angular client. However I am getting the date field like '/Date(1546120800000+0200)/' in the service response. How can I convert it into 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm' in the Angular client (Angular version 6) ?

Comment: Hello and welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

This solution may work out for you:

```
d= new Date(1546120800000+0200).toLocaleString();
```

Answer (score 0):

When serializing data of type Datetime, it will show the format. You could use [OnSerializing] and [OnDeserialized] attribute to help format your datatime.

[OnSerializing] will be triggered before your data model is serialized.

So you could format your datatime to string, and set a data member of type string to the formatted string. Then wcf will serialize the formatted property of your model.

For more information , you could refer to the link below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c5d8c90-cc99-452a-8276-18b1e978758c/how-do-i-get-a-datetime-param-to-serialize-in-a-specific-format-with-wcf-rest?forum=wcf

Please pay attention to the updated model's DataMember attribute, property of type datatime has no [DataMember] attribute, and another property performanceDateSerialized(which contains the formatted Datetime) of type string has the attribute DataMember.